# Is combining a Junk Dimension with a Conformed Dimension in a single table advisable for efficient data management?

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship, dimensional-modeling

In the process of optimizing the product dimension in the data lake for PowerBI analytics, a challenge has emerged where each department has a distinct product dimension with specific features. This results in complications when generating cross-department reports due to varying SKs assigned to the same product.

To address this issue, [a proposed solution involves creating a master product dimension for a unified source of truth](https://www.dataversity.net/what-is-master-data-management-and-why-is-it-important/#:%7E:text=Improved%20Data%20Quality%3A%20Master%20Data,businesses%20to%20make%20better%20decisions.), which actually turns out to be what Kimball calls [Conformed Dimensions](https://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/conformed-dimension/). However, concerns have been raised regarding potential complexity, particularly because of the low-cardinality in sales and marketing that drive us also to a kind of [Junk Dimension](https://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/junk-dimension/), and the inclusion of finance products not present in other departments.

I undertook the following exercise to gain insight into the potential behavior of this master data. As you can observe below, the number of lines is anticipated to be substantial. This is due to the fact that, for every combination of product and features, an individual line would be generated, distinguished by a unique SKU identifier.

How can scalability and management issues be mitigated in a data system that incorporates tables with mixed 'Junk' and 'Conformed' dimensions? Are there established best practices for handling such data structures, or is this approach generally discouraged based on factual evidence?

[image]

Here is my ddl code example with a synthetic data:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP_PRODUCT_SALES (
    sk INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    product_id INT,
    SLS_feature1 VARCHAR(255),
    SLS_feature2 VARCHAR(255)
);


INSERT INTO #TEMP_PRODUCT_SALES (product_id, SLS_feature1, SLS_feature2)
VALUES
    (1, 'A', 'X'),
(1, 'A', 'Y'),
(1, 'A', 'Z'),
(2, 'B', 'X'),
(2, 'B', 'Y'),
(2, 'B', 'Z'),
(3, 'C', 'X'),
(3, 'C', 'Y'),
(3, 'C', 'Z');


CREATE TABLE #TEMP_PRODUCT_marketing (
    sk INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    product_id INT,
    mkt_feature1 VARCHAR(255),
    mkt_feature2 VARCHAR(255)
);


INSERT INTO #TEMP_PRODUCT_marketing (product_id, mkt_feature1, mkt_feature2)
VALUES
    (1, 'M1', 'N1'),
    (1, 'M1', 'N2'),
    (1, 'M1', 'N3'),
    (2, 'M2', 'N2'),
    (3, 'M3', 'N3');

-- Create PRODUCT_finance temporary table
CREATE TABLE #TEMP_PRODUCT_finance (
    sk INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    product_id INT,
    fin_feature1 VARCHAR(255),
    fin_feature2 VARCHAR(255)
);


INSERT INTO #TEMP_PRODUCT_finance (product_id, fin_feature1, fin_feature2)
VALUES
    (1, 'F1', 'G1'),
    (2, 'F2', 'G2'),
    (3, 'F3', 'G3'),
    (4, 'F2', 'G2');


CREATE TABLE #TEMP_Conformed_Dimension (
    sk INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    product_id INT,
    SLS_feature1 VARCHAR(255),
    SLS_feature2 VARCHAR(255),
    mkt_feature1 VARCHAR(255),
    mkt_feature2 VARCHAR(255),
    fin_feature1 VARCHAR(255),
    fin_feature2 VARCHAR(255)
);



INSERT INTO #TEMP_Conformed_Dimension (product_id, SLS_feature1, SLS_feature2, mkt_feature1, mkt_feature2, fin_feature1, fin_feature2)
SELECT
    p.product_id,
    ps.SLS_feature1,
    ps.SLS_feature2,
    pm.mkt_feature1,
    pm.mkt_feature2,
    pf.fin_feature1,
    pf.fin_feature2
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM #TEMP_PRODUCT_SALES) p
    LEFT JOIN #TEMP_PRODUCT_SALES ps ON p.product_id = ps.product_id
    LEFT JOIN #TEMP_PRODUCT_marketing pm ON p.product_id = pm.product_id
    LEFT JOIN #TEMP_PRODUCT_finance pf ON p.product_id = pf.product_id;


INSERT INTO #TEMP_Conformed_Dimension (product_id, SLS_feature1, SLS_feature2, mkt_feature1, mkt_feature2, fin_feature1, fin_feature2)
SELECT
    product_id,
    SLS_feature1,
    SLS_feature2,
    NULL AS mkt_feature1,
     NULL AS mkt_feature2,
     NULL AS fin_feature1,
    NULL AS fin_feature2
FROM
    #TEMP_PRODUCT_SALES
WHERE
    product_id NOT IN (SELECT product_id FROM #TEMP_Conformed_Dimension)
UNION
SELECT
    product_id,
    NULL AS SLS_feature1,
    NULL AS SLS_feature2,
     mkt_feature1,
     mkt_feature2,
    NULL AS fin_feature1,
    NULL AS fin_feature2
FROM
    #TEMP_PRODUCT_marketing
WHERE
    product_id NOT IN (SELECT product_id FROM #TEMP_Conformed_Dimension)
UNION
SELECT
    product_id,
    NULL AS SLS_feature1,
    NULL AS SLS_feature2,
    NULL AS mkt_feature1,
    NULL AS mkt_feature2,
    fin_feature1,
     fin_feature2
FROM
    #TEMP_PRODUCT_finance
WHERE
    product_id NOT IN (SELECT product_id FROM #TEMP_Conformed_Dimension);


SELECT * FROM #TEMP_Conformed_Dimension;
```

Comment: you would only put those data in external tables if they are not needed everytime, the second cause to have those 1:1 tables is if the row is to big, so you would put rarely uses columns in external table. we try to vaoid joins that are not necessary as they cause overhead, that can be better spent

Comment: Thanks, @nbk. I Appreciate your input. To clarify, I require all columns from each product dimension. However, consolidating them into a single "TEMP_Conformed_Dimension" may result in significant width and size. What's your perspective on this approach, considering scalability( additional low-cardinality attributes) and its overall manageability?

Comment: you use views or even materialized views and not join them together, if the row is alrady very big, you could pack all sub tables i one sub table, then you need only one join or two if the data is too big to hold them in one table

Comment: Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461) [Why is asking a question on "best practice" a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142353/266284)
 [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) It is unhelpful & unclear to ask 'A or B' when A & B are not mutually exclusive and/or not the only options. (And you may think they are when they are not.) Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. PS [mre]

Comment: This scenario is covered chapter 10 of Kimball’s Data Warehouse Toolkit. Start at the section “Supertype and Subtype Schemas for Heterogeneous Products”